# Sum aggregation on Unique Data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to get total unique record and sum of amount of those unique data. How to get it in Elastic Search query.My Sample input data is

```
{"amt":"2.9",
"recName":"Item2",
"recID":"r1",
"exeDate":"2022-03-19T02:51:06.948Z",
"inputDate":"2022-03-19"}
{"amt":"2.9",
"recName":"Item2",
"recID":"r1",
"exeDate":"2022-03-19T02:52:06.948Z",
"inputDate":"2022-03-19"}
{"amt":"1.8",
"recName":"Item1",
"recID":"r2",
"exeDate":"2022-03-19T02:51:06.948Z",
"inputDate":"2022-03-19"}
```

I am expecting output:

```
recName: Item1, Item2
recNameCount : 2
amount: 4.7
```

Answer (score 1):

First, You can defind index mapping which have field `amt` as `float` type. like below:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "amt":{
        "type": "float"
      },
      "recName":{
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After, You can use aggregation for your expected result as below:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "RecName": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "recName",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "amount": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "amt"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "unique_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "recName"
      }
    },
    "sum_total":{
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "RecName>amount"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- First use [Term Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on `recName` field which will give unique name.
- Second use [Avg Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html) on `amt` field (inner aggregation inside`RecName` to just get amout per item).
- Third, use [Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) on `recName` field for getting distinct values.
- Forth, use [Sum Bucket Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html) to sum on `amt` field.

**Response**

```json
"aggregations" : {
    "RecName" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Item1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "amount" : {
            "value" : 1.7999999523162842
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Item2",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "amount" : {
            "value" : 2.9000000953674316
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "unique_count" : {
      "value" : 2
    },
    "sum_total" : {
      "value" : 4.700000047683716
    }
  }
```

Comment: can present the same visually

Comment: Sorry i didnt get what you means @NadaNasser

Comment: I mean to build a visualization data table to present the output on Kibana dashboard. How to set the query elements when building a kibana visualization